# How to Unable/Disable Copy & Paste in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

When the XLS document is opened, I want to prevent the contents of the document can not be copied Is it possible to disable Copy & Paste function in PHPExcel?

Comment: Yes... with javascript you can capture the Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V shortcuts and prevent their default behaviour... Personally I would crucify you for doing so though...

Comment: Than the answer NO should suffice

Comment: Security options available in PHPExcel are described in section `4.6.26` of the developer documentation, entitled `Setting security on a spreadsheet`

Comment: @RichardBernards - An XLS document isn't a web page viewed through a web browser, and doesn't have any associated javascript